# C# - MergeSort, running out of memory

Tags: c#, mergesort

I implemented MergeSort algorithm that's used on a 100,000 integer file. It takes care of the sorting and collects inversions that are in the file. It works with small test arrays, but as soon as I plug in the actual file, I get out of memory error. How do I fix it?
The error occurs during MergeSort, and the number of elements in my aux array is 12,500
Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment_1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> data = File2Array("IntegerArray.txt");
            int[] unsorted = data.ToArray();
            List<string> inversions = new List<string>();
            Sort(ref unsorted, ref inversions);
            Console.WriteLine("number of inversions is: " + inversions.Count());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Sort(ref int[] unsorted, ref List<string>inversions)
        {
            int size = unsorted.Length;
            if (size == 1)
                return;
            int mid = size / 2;
            int leftSize = mid;
            int rightSize = size - leftSize;
            int[] left = new int[leftSize];
            int[] right = new int[rightSize];
            Array.Copy(unsorted, 0, left, 0, leftSize);
            Array.Copy(unsorted, mid, right, 0, rightSize);
            Sort(ref left, ref inversions);
            Sort(ref right, ref inversions);

            int[] aux = new int[leftSize + rightSize];
            for (int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; k < aux.Length; k++)
            {
                if (left[i] < right[j])
                {
                    aux[k] = left[i++];
                    // if left array is exhausted, copy the remaining right array elements over
                    if (i == leftSize)
                    {
                        Array.Copy(right, j, aux, ++k, rightSize - j);
                        unsorted = aux;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    int temp = i;
                    while (temp < leftSize)
                    {
                        inversions.Add(left[temp++] + "-" + right[j]);
                    }
                    aux[k] = right[j++];
                    if (j == rightSize)
                    {
                        Array.Copy(left, i, aux, ++k, leftSize - i);
                        unsorted = aux;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static List<int> File2Array(string file)
        {
            List<int> data = new List<int>();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file))
            {
                int line;
                do
                {
                    int.TryParse(reader.ReadLine(), out line);
                    data.Add(line);
                }
                while (!reader.EndOfStream);
            }
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet you have an infinite loop here.

Comment: No infinite loop. I tested it with multiple inputs of smaller size and everything was ok.

Comment: It seems to me you're storing 2 copies of the data.  One as a List and the other as an array.  Stick with one or the other.  also your sort routine is making more copies recursively.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do it this way?  Are you determined to solve the problem with your sort or are you open to alternative data structures to solve your problem?

Comment: I would rewrite it without the array allocations at each recursion. Try passing indexes around instead.

Comment: It's an algorithm class on coursera. Professor instructed to use merge sort and get the number of inversions this way.

Comment: Well your solution is going to unnecessarily consume a lot of memory. Sort with a 100000 element array is going to allocate 2 50000 element arrays and recurse, and then each of those 2 recursions is going to allocate 2 25000 element arrays until you get to the end and have 50000 2 element arrays. I think you'd be allocating 100000 at each recursion and would need 16+ recursions to reach the bottom.

Comment: I solved the problem. Using a list to store inversions was causing the problem. It's using the doubling resize algorithm, so that could be why. I just replaced it with a long counter and everything worked (I got 2,407,905,288 inversions), this is the correct answer, too. Left and Right arrays were not the problem. IIRC, variables that reference the arrays are just pointers, so when I allocate new space for L or R, the old space is free to be abused by other programs. But yeah, I'll need to rewrite it to use the same chunk of memory.

Comment: When you allocate space for `L` and `R` in the _next level of recursion_ the arrays above are retained.  By the time you get down to your first merge operation you've allocated 2 * log2(n) arrays with a total of ~n*2 spaces, and filled them all with data copied from the original array.  At worst you should be allocating once per merge operation for temporary sort space - bottom-up allocation rather than top-down.

Comment: Does anyone have a link to a GOOD implementation of merge sort? I can read C, C# or Java. I'm scanning through google and I can't find anything good. The code is either sloppy, similar to mine with space allocation on each recursive call, or uses lists (which I'm trying to avoid here.)

Comment: @haosmark - this one looks reasonable: http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/MergeSort_Recursive.html

Comment: Doesn't look like it's following C# code conventions, and it creates a 25 element array with each run. Looks like a poor implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code for you to look at.

This starts with recognizing that the file is already a collection of single elements.  Therefore we can do the first grouping/sorting when we read the file.  Since arrays are very impractical for this part I used Lists and then cast the return to int[][]

```
static int[][] makearrays(string filename)
{
    List<List<int>> outval = new List<List<int>>();
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            int a = 0, b = 0;
            a = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            if(!sr.EndOfStream)
                b = int.Parse(sr.ReadLine());
            else
            {
                outval.Add(new List<int>() { a });
                break;
            }
            if(a > b)
                outval.Add(new List<int>() { b, a });
            else
                outval.Add(new List<int>() { a, b });

        }
    }
    return outval.Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
}
```

With this array we can start the rest of the grouping/sorting

This uses recursion but has a minimal memory footprint:

```
static int[][] dosort(int[][] input)
{
    if(input.Length == 1)
        return input;
    int i = 1, m = 0;
    for(; i < input.Length; i += 2)
    {
        int limit = Math.Min(input[i].Length, input[i - 1].Length);
        int[] temp = new int[input[i].Length + input[i - 1].Length];
        int j = 0, k = 0, l = 0;
        while(j < input[i].Length && k < input[i - 1].Length)
        {
            if(input[i][j] < input[i - 1][k])
            {
                temp[l++] = input[i][j++];
            }
            else
                temp[l++] = input[i - 1][k++];
        }
        while(l < temp.Length)
        {
            if(j < input[i].Length)
                temp[l++] = input[i][j++];
            if(k < input[i - 1].Length)
                temp[l++] = input[i - 1][k++];
        }
        input[m++] = temp;
    }
    if(input.Length % 2 == 1)
        input[m++] = input.Last();
    input = input.Take(m).ToArray();
    return dosort(input);
}
```

In my tests the 100000 element file was sorted in less than a quarter of a second, including reading it into memory.

Comment: Interesting approach, thanks, I'll study this code. Mine took a little over 0.5 seconds for reading and sorting

Comment: I forgot to mention the resulting array will only have one array in it with all the original elements sorted